# The source file is different from when the module was built?

Tags: vb.net

Mediocre VB.Net student here, but not a total noob. I've been getting this error: "The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger to use it anyway?"

I chose Form1.vb on the "Find Source: Form1.vb" open file dialog box that followed. After that, my program has been acting very weirdly. For example, I have codes inside the sub that handles Button1 click, and then I moved those codes somewhere. Now when debugging, when I click that button, it executes the codes that I just removed a minute ago!

I'm scared because I don't to waste the 2 months of hard work that I've already spent on this project. Too friggin stupid to remember to backup the whole thing. Stackoverflow, please don't fail me now.

Comment: First off don't make changes while you're debugging.  It usually doesn't hurt to do incremental builds while you're coding as well.

Comment: Your comment suggests you have two months worth of work that you're worried about losing. This implies you're not using source control. If you're not using source control for such a lot of work, I strongly recommend to!

Answer (score 1):

As you have explained i think the scenario is your modified code is not build correctly.. once rebuild the entire solution.

Please be sure work in debug mode, and then try Clean solution and then "Rebuild All".

refer following links may also help you..

[the source file is different from when the module was built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087390/the-source-file-is-different-from-when-the-module-was-built)

[Warning given when debugging source code in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926932/warning-given-when-debugging-source-code-in-visual-studio-2010)